# Parsing a DN from certificate in pem format (correct order)

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, x509, client-certificates

I have seen a few posts related to parsing DN from a certificate in PEM format. I am writing a UNIX script that will read the pem files in a given path and spits out their corresponding Distinguished Name (DN) in the correct order. Created a simple script but the command that parses the pem file within the script is..

**openssl x509 -in <*file name.pem*> -noout -subject**

My confusion is when I run the above command, it spits the DN in this order starting with /C=US/ST=...but I know for a fact that the certificate DN starts with "CN=" which is exact reverse of what the command is spitting out. I am having a hard time trusting which command to run that gives me the exact order because I use that order to authenticate the user and if I onboard with the wrong order, requests will not be authorized and it defeats the purpose.

Comment: I think you can reliably consider the DN supplied by openssl is in reverse order and if you reverse the key-value pairs, it should be a proper DN.

A reference regarding it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33769978/why-does-nginx-provide-the-client-ssl-dn-in-reverse-order

This section (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1779#section-2.3) provides the attributes for CN and I am assuming they are in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the component of the DN is a matter of convention. 
The physical order inside the binary DER encoding is the one OpenSSL shows you here. 
OTOH the reverted order you expected is the one that a majority of tools use and that was normalized in RFC 2253.

This "/C=US/ST=..." format is the old OpenSSL one and now obsolete. If that's the one you get by default with OpenSSL, then you're using a very old version and should probably replace it with a more recent one.

In order to control how OpenSSL will display the subject, you need to use the *-nameopt* option. The value you can use are : 
*-nameopt rfc2253* : the order you wish, and the name will be "CN=xxx,OU=xxx,ST=xxx,C=FR" (no space, reverse order).
*-nameopt oneline* : the name will be "C = FR, ST = xxx , OU = xxx , CN = xxx".
*-nameopt compat* : the name will be "/C=US/ST=xxx/OU=xxx/CN=xxx" (without the space).

One more thing, if you compare the string of the DN to authenticate a client, the only way to get a reasonably reliable result is to use the *exact* same tool to generate it initially and when you verify it. As soon as a DN contains a less usual element, there's too many variations between tools to get the same string representation of the DN when not using the same one and the same version.